# How can I do this? Adding invalid input options

Tags: javascript

I want to make a feature in my code where if you type an invalid input then it says it's invalid and will force you to repeat until you either type '1' or '2'. The game is about typing a random number between 1 and 2 and if it's right number the dragon will give you a treasure in the form of a message. If it isn't he will eat you, which is again a message. So far what I'm trying to do just isn't working.

This is my code so far (javascript):

```
alert("You are in a land full of dragons. In front of you, you see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly and will share his treasure with you. The other dragon is greedy and hungry, and will eat you on sight.");

var person = prompt("Which cave will you go into? Please either type 1 or 2");

alert("You approach the cave");
alert("It's dark and spooky..");

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

var invalid = person !== 1 || person !== 2;

while (invalid) {
  alert("This input is invalid");
 var person = prompt("Which cave will you go into? Please either type 1 or 2");
 }

if (person == random) {
   alert("A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and... Gives you a treasure                    Do you want to play again?"); 
} else{
   alert("A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and.. gobbles you down in one bite! Do you want to play again?");
}
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant HTML and any CSS as well.

Comment: The invalid check seems like a bug.  `1 !== 2` and `2 !== 1`.  It will always be invalid.  A single variable cannot be equal to two separate values strictly.

Comment: It needs to be an `&&` not an `||`

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's not working because of the strict comparison of string with an integer. The `person` variable that you're receiving is a string, but you're making a strict comparison that checks the type here:

```
var invalid = person !== 1 || person !== 2;
```

So type converting might help. Use unary `+` operator in front of both the `person` to convert it into integer and do a strict comparison and also it should be `&&` and not `||`:

```
var invalid = +person !== 1 && +person !== 2;
```

Also, there's no way this will come out of the loop, if it's invalid. So please take care of that as well. Also, here a `do ... while` loop makes more sense. I have updated that code in the below snippet:

```js
alert("You are in a land full of dragons. In front of you, you see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly and will share his treasure with you. The other dragon is greedy and hungry, and will eat you on sight.");

alert("You approach the cave");
alert("It's dark and spooky..");

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

do {
  var person = prompt("Which cave will you go into? Please either type 1 or 2");
  var invalid = +person !== 1 && +person !== 2;
  if (invalid)
    alert("This input is invalid");
} while (invalid);

if (person == random) {
  alert("A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and... Gives you a treasure                    Do you want to play again?");
} else {
  alert("A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and.. gobbles you down in one bite! Do you want to play again?");
}
```

<sup>Answer updates and fixes credit [Taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar) and [FZs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8376184/fzs).</sup>

Comment: @Taplar Fixed it. Thanks. Was confused what you were trying to tell and got it clarified now.

Comment: Why not use a `do..while` loop? You could just drop the prompt and the validity check into it...

Answer (score -1):

You could use a while loop that waits until the user enters in a 1 or 2. Also, you would have to check every single time so something like this would be better.

```
    while (invalid) {
        alert("This input is invalid");
        person = prompt("Which cave will you go into? Please either type 1 or 2");
        invalid = parseInt(person) === 1 || parseInt(person) === 2;
    }
```

Comment: `x !== 1 || x !== 2` is always true

Comment: Fixed it. Now it is either the variable person is 1 or 2.

Comment: That didn't fix anything.  A single value cannot strictly equal to different values.  If the value is `1`, that statement will be true because the first part will be true.  If the value is `2` that statement will be true because the first part is false, but the || is true because the second part is true.  If the value is `3`, invalid will be false because 3 is not 1 or 2, but that **is an invalid value** because the user wants them to only choose 1 or 2.

Comment: There's also the issue of type comparison.  string 1 is not `===` to integer 1.